# unformatted input to a std::string instead of c-string from binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, cstring, stdstring

ok i have this program working using c-strings.  I am wondering if it is possible to read in blocks of unformatted text to a std::string?  I toyed arround with `if >>` but this reads in line by line.  I've been breaking my code and banging my head against the wall trying to use std::string, so I thought it was time to enlist the experts.  Here's a working program you need to supply a file "a.txt" with some content to make it run.

i tried to fool around with:

```
in.read (const_cast<char *>(memblock.c_str()), read_size);
```

but it was acting odd.  I had to do `std::cout << memblock.c_str()` to get it to print. and `memblock.clear()` did not clear out the string.

anyway, if you can think of a way to use STL I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's my program using c-strings

```
// What this program does now:  copies a file to a new location byte by byte
// What this program is going to do: get small blocks of a file and encrypt them
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
 int read_size = 16;
 int infile_size;
 std::ifstream in;
 std::ofstream out;
 char * memblock;
 int completed = 0;

 memblock = new char [read_size];
 in.open ("a.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
 if (in.is_open())
  infile_size = in.tellg();
 out.open("b.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);

 in.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);// get to beginning of file

 while(!in.eof())
 {
  completed = completed + read_size;
  if(completed < infile_size)
  {
   in.read (memblock, read_size);
   out.write (memblock, read_size);
  } // end if
  else // last run
  {
   delete[] memblock;
   memblock = new char [infile_size % read_size];
   in.read (memblock, infile_size % read_size + 1);
   out.write (memblock, infile_size % read_size );
  } // end else
 } // end while
} // main
```

if you see anything that would make this code better please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I don't really understand your problems with `std::string`:  what do you mean that you had to call `c_str()` to print the contents and that `clear()` did not clear the string?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using a `std::string`, consider using a `std::vector<char>`; that gets you around all the problems with doing a `const_cast` on the result of calling `std::string::c_str()`.  Just resize the vector to whatever size you need before you start using it.

If you want to print the contents, you can null-terminate the contents of the vector by pushing a null-terminator onto the back:

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.push_back('\0');
std::cout << &v[0];
```

or you can convert it into a `std::string`:

```
std::vector<char> v;
std::string s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

This all assumes that you have some block of text that you want to read from a binary file.  If you are trying to print out binary characters, this won't work, obviously.  It wasn't entirely clear from your question.

Comment: Why not just use the string just like the vector here? `&myString[0]`

Comment: @Billy:  Hmmmm.  That's a good idea; I guess I never thought of that. `:-P`  For better or worse, I think I've sort of blocked out anything that relies on the elements of `std::string` being stored contiguously, given the amount of debate there has been over that topic.